# How can I use ThreadingLayer to perform operations with layers of different dimmensions?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Is there a way that I can achieve subtraction between a scalar and a vector within `NetGraph[]`, similar to what happens when I perform `{1, 2, 3}-1` to get `{0,1,2}`? For my purposes, this needs to be done within `NetGraph[]` for timing and functional reasons. Part of the trouble is that the vector also will be changing in size. Is there already a `NetGraph[]` layer that has these functionalities?

For those who want a little more background, I am trying to create a filter within my network as part of the loss function, where the data being fed into the network spans over just two days and each day (of the week) is represented as a value between `0` and `1`. So Monday is represented as `0.0` and Tuesday as `0.2` and so forth.

I am using `SequenceLastLayer[]` to get the time of the last bar of data, and am attempting to use this in conjunction with a slightly modified `Tanh[]` function within `ThreadingLayer[]`, as well as the bars with the other time values whose form will be similar to `{.0,.0,.0,...,.2,.2,.2,}`. So the one scalar, in this example, would be `0.2` and the vector would be `{.0,.0,.0,...,.2,.2,.2,}`, and the operation would be:

```
`{.0,.0,.0,...,.2,.2,.2,} - 0.2`
```

This seems like it should be relatively simple, but I have not yet been able to figure it out. Does anyone know what I can do differently?

Here is the code so far:

```
net = NetGraph[<|"thread" -> ThreadingLayer[#1*#2 &], 
   "getLastLayer" -> 
    SequenceLastLayer[]|>, {NetPort["timeInput"] -> {"getLastLayer", 
     "thread"}, "getLastLayer" -> "thread"}]
```

[image]

And the code to run it would be similar to:

```
net[<|"timeInput" -> {0.0,0.0,0.0,...,0.2,0.2,0.2,}|>]
```

Comment: `ThreadingLayer` supports broadcasting now, so it can be done like `"thread" -> ThreadingLayer[Times, 1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with ReplicateLayer:

```
subtractionLayer = NetGraph[
  {ReplicateLayer[Automatic], ThreadingLayer[#1 - #2 &]},
  {NetPort["Scalar"] -> 1, {NetPort["Vector"], 1} -> 2}
  ];
subtractionLayer[<|"Vector" -> {1, 2, 3}, "Scalar" -> 1|>]
(* {0., 1., 2.} *)
```

The "scalar" can also be an array with one less dimensions than the "vector":

```
subtractionLayer[<|"Vector" -> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}, "Scalar" -> {0, 1}|>]
(* {{1., 0.}, {2., 1.}, {3., 2.}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome!